# ACF Custom field not showing in Timber Taxonomy page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, categories

### Issue: I am unable to display ACF custom fields while looping through taxonomies.

I have an ACF text field called 'icon'. After applying it to my custom taxonomy 'topic' (and categories while troubleshooting) it displays as intended on the taxonomy archive page. However when I list the taxonomy on any other page I cannot access the ACF field, just the standard fields.

As this is used globally on several pages, I currently have this in my functions:

```
$context['topicTax'] = get_terms('topic');
```

And in the .twig template:

```
{% for item in topicTax %}
   <li>
       <p>{{ item.meta('icon') }} {{ item.name }}</p>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

I have also tried

```
$context['topicTax'] = Timber::get_terms('topic');
$context['topicTax'] = $topicTax;
```

but this doesn't display anything.

I found [this post](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/returning-custom-field-values-including-terms-on-term-archive-pages/) to have a similar issue (though not using Timber) but have not managed to replicate the solution.

---

Though I have been using twig for several years, I am still fairly new to Wordpress, and have skipped straight to Timber. Apologies if I am overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In your PHP file...

```
$context['topicTax'] = Timber::get_terms('topic');
Timber::render('my-template.twig', $context);
```

... is the correct structure. The problem is that WP's `get_terms` returns "dumb" objects that don't have methods for retrieving ACF info. If you still run into issues, verify that those objects are `Timber\Term`s rather than `WP_Term`

Also, if you're looking for the more active forum: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timber) is where I normally manage/do support

Comment: Thank you for the reply, in the future I will post on StackOverflow. This is something I tried, though after taking your advice I have a different issue.

This line of code, or rather adding Timber:: in front of get_terms('topic'); renders the page blank, or not at all.

I have tried renaming the variable to topicTaxonomy to make sure there is no conflict elsewhere, and I have tried isolating this to a single page rather than globally in my functions file.

Comment: Scratch that, while testing I had left behind some broken code. This worked, thank you Jared!

Comment: You bet, glad it worked!